# Textarea char count fail on page load

Tags: javascript, events, textarea, html

English is not my native idiom, so apologies in advance for bad grammar.

I am using a javascript to count the characters of a textarea, the code work smoothly showing the character limit decreasing when typing, using this code i called on the textarea a php method to call from a database a text, and heres is where the problem comes, when testing the page at load it show the text on the textarea but the character limit stay on 500, ofcourse it change value if u type on the textarea showing the correct character limit.

How do i manage to show the correct character limit when the page load?

here is my code:

**HTML CODE:**

```
<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="4">
<textarea "rows="10" cols="35" onKeyPress="return charLimit(this)" onKeyUp="return characterCount(this)"><?php echo $oRep->getDescripcion(); ?> </textarea> 
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="center" colspan="4"><p><strong><span id="charCount">500</span></strong> Caracteres disponibles.</p></td>
</tr>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
var maxLength=500;
function charLimit(el) {
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) return false;
    return true;
}
function characterCount(el) {
    var charCount = document.getElementById('charCount');
    if (el.value.length > maxLength) el.value = el.value.substring(0,maxLength);
    if (charCount) charCount.innerHTML = maxLength - el.value.length;
    return true;
}
```

i be tried to add a event on the textarea like `onchange="return charLimit(this)` but with no change.

Comment: Please post the correct javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this `<body onload="characterCount(document.getElementById('text'))">` to your body tag and make the id of the textarea as "text".

Comment: Thx a lot it worked! i was trying to put that event on the textarea silly me.

Comment: That wouldn't work because of two reasons, when the textarea is loaded, the charcount span is not. Also, the onload event doesn't exist for textarea.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'll add an id for that textarea, let's say 'descriptionTextArea'.
Secondly, I'll listen for 'onload' event on body (for instance), and inside onload handler I'd  do this:

```
// get reference to body
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

// listening for onload event
body.addEventListener('load', loadHandler);

function loadHandler() {
    // get reference to our description text area
    var descriptionTextArea = document.getElementById('descriptionTextArea');

    // call method with reference to descriptionTextArea as parameter
    characterCount(descriptionTextArea);
}
```

This way, we call 'characterCount' method on page load, and it should correctly calculate the character count without user interaction.

Comment: it work as well but got a little confused with the body call method.